# How to chop and reshape/melt a table or CSV file

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a CSV file which contains `min` and `max` values for each variable like this:

```
original = """
min_a max_a min_b max_b
3 5 1 9
"""
```

The first row is sorted in variable names, so it is guaranteed that it goes from `min_a` to `max_z`. I want to reshape/melt it in chunks like so:

```
goal = """
 min max
a 3 5
b 1 9
"""
```

How can I do that? I feel like [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) or a numpy method can be used here, but couldn't figure out how. My current "hack" is to reshape the second row of values as follows, and copy-paste or write the result into CSV:

```
orig = "3 5 1 9"
temp = orig.split()
chopped = [" ".join(temp[i:i+2]+["\n"]) for i in range(0,3,2)]
# chopped: ['3', '5', '1', '9']
ready = [" min max \n"] + [" ".join(e) for e in zip(['a','b'],chopped)]
# ready: [' min max \n', 'a 3 5 \n', 'b 1 9 \n']
flipped = "".join(ready)
# flipped: ' min max \na 3 5 \nb 1 9 \n'
print(flipped)
# Result:
#  min max
# a 3 5 
# b 1 9
```

Is there a proper way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by `split` and then is possible use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
   max  min
a    5    3
b    9    1
```

**Setup**:

```
original = """
min_a max_a min_b max_b
3 5 1 9
"""
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(original), sep="\s+")
print (df)
   min_a  max_a  min_b  max_b
0      3      5      1      9
1      4      6      2     10
```